# ANR in android.media.MediaPlayer.release

Tags: android, webview

We're seeing quite a lot of ANRs in "android.media.MediaPlayer.release" for a WebView-based production app.

The main thread seems to get stuck at:

```
at android.media.MediaPlayer._release (Native method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.release (MediaPlayer.java:1722)
at org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerBridge.release (MediaPlayerBridge.java:155)
at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce (Native method)
at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage (SystemMessageHandler.java:41)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:234)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5526)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Apparently the WebView is unable to release it's media player. That's about the only clue provided by the ANR report.

The app has heavy use of video playback, so it's probably related to this.

Any suggestion for a workaround is very much appreciated.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issues. Did you find the cause/fix/ workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately we've never found a fix for this!

Comment: I'm having a spike of these ANRs, did you ever find anything about it?

Comment: Hi Casolorz, I left the project years ago. To my knowledge, we never found a workaround for this. Maybe file a report in Googles issue-tracker, if you're still seeing this issue with recent OS versions. Cheers.